# Spring security requires authentication for pages marked with "anonymous" or "permitAll"

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot

My application has an authenticated admin area. My problem is that it also requires authentication for the login page (although it's marked as either "anonymous" or "permitAll" - I've tried both).

My configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.antMatcher("/admin/**")
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/login.html", "/admin/logout.html").permitAll() //"anonymous()" has same result
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "PUBLISHER")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .addFilter(preAuthenticationFilter())
            .addFilter(adminExceptionTranslationFilter())
            .csrf().disable()
            .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/admin/logout.html"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/index.html")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true);
}
```

The only thing I could think of that might be the culprit is the `preAuthenticationFilter` which extends the `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` class (the authentication is smart card based and that class extracts the credential from a certificate sent by the browser). I'm guess that maybe because it's a type of **pre**Authenticated filter, then maybe Spring runs it before any request - thus prompting the authentication request in the browser (even if the accessed page "/admin/login.html" doesn't require authentication).

So my question ultimately is how do I actually disable authentication for the login page? As far as I can tell from the documentation, the `antMatcher`s are configured correctly.

Comment: Try changing your antMatchers to be for the path not the file/view. `.antMatchers("/admin/login/**", "/admin/logout/**").permitAll()`

Comment: What's the point of that? Nothing exists in the path matched by `"/admin/login/**"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a proxy problem. The code in question is correct.

Comment: Would have been helpful if you had elaborated.

Comment: @CodeMed the problem was that a proxy server wasn't correctly serving the client smart card certificate required for authentication.